# map/set erase iterator out of range

Tags: c++, dictionary, sfml

When I close my app in a certain state, this code runs:

```
void GameEndState::exit(){
    delete m_pGameObjectManager;
    delete m_pSceneManager;
}
```

After running m_pGameObjectManager's destructor, which is:

```
GameObjectManager::~GameObjectManager(){
    std::for_each(gameObjects.begin(),gameObjects.end(),GameObjectDeallocator());
}
//gameObjects is a std::map<sf::String,VisibleGameObject*>

///////////////

struct GameObjectDeallocator{
        void operator()(const std::pair<sf::String,VisibleGameObject*>&p) const{
            delete p.second;
        }
    };
```

it will produce the title's error. I haven't found any results of this error from googling. I am using SFML 2.0.

VisibleGameObject's destructor:

```
VisibleGameObject::~VisibleGameObject(){
    m_pSceneManager->removeSprite(name);
}

void SceneManager::removeSprite(sf::String spritename){
    std::cout << "removed " << std::string(spritename) << std::endl;
    sprites.erase(sprites.find(spritename));
}

//sprites is a std::map<sf::String,sf::Sprite>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think the error is produced by the code fragment you have provided. I see no map erase in the snippets here. What is VisibleGameObject? Maybe it's destructor calls the erase?

Comment: Oops, I had meant to include them. Editing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in this line, evidently `sprites.find` is not finding the name you've given it and is returning `sprites.end()`.

```
sprites.erase(sprites.find(spritename));
```

Comment: Oh, that was simple. I was only looking at the destructor of gameobjectmnager before! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may simply call erase with a key, no need to pass an iterator to it(unless you are using a multimap which I think is not the case): `sprites.erase(spritename);` Still this code is not very good as it may try to erase an non-existent element. So you better go for:

```
std::map<sf::String,sf::Sprite>::iterator iter = sprites.find(spritename);
if (iter != sprites.end()) {
  sprites.erase(iter);
}
```